# Can anyone help me how can I make this gradient background in flutter? (The image is given below)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, gradient

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/immdJ.jpg)

I do not understand how can I make these rotated small rectangle gradients here. I am really confused.

Comment: it is too complex to compose it from the existing 'bricks' - most likely you need a `CustomPaint` widget

Comment: Your best case is to just pull down an image with this background or as pskink said, use a CustomPaint widget.

Comment: Thanks! I solved this issue with the help of stack and transform widget. I created a rectangle box and rotated it with the help of transform and with the help of stack I have put it in the desired places. I don't know whether its a good idea or not but works for now. what do you guys say?